# Admin Access to Collaborators in Github

Tags: github

I have a Repository where I want to add Collaborators and give the admin access so that they can perform a Push on the Master Branch without having the need to create a PR.

I believe it can be achieved by going to Setting ----> Collaborators and Select the Role of the Collaborator next to their name.

But when I go to the Collaborators list I do not see a dropdown to select the role right next to their name, instead this is what I see.

[Manage Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OBSc.png)